# Difference between rpy2 code evaluation methods

Tags: python, r, rpy2

rpy2 can evaluate R code in a couple different methods:

Method A -evaluate a string as R code

```
import rpy2.robjects as rob
rcode = '''
print(summary(mtcars))
'''
rob.r(rcode)
```

Method B -evaluate R code through python objects

```
import rpy2.robjects as rob
rsummary = rob.r['summary']
mtcars = rob.r('mtcars')
print rsummary(mtcars)
```

The [rpy2 documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/robjects.html#evaluating-a-string-as-r-code) warns against method A because "*Doing this with large objects might not be the best use of your computing power.*"  Why is that? Are there known benchmarks?

I prefer method A because it is easier for me to follow, it keeps the two languages separated, and I can just stuff in existing R code snippets. However, I want to know more about what I will be sacrificing by going that route.  Any insight into this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This all comes down to dealing with data -- if you don't have any data in python, by all means use method A.

Method A is pretty much equivalent to running R using a subprocess. Imagine using python to create a file script.R, and then running that script -- this would work fine until you start dealing with large amounts of data.

Here's an example:

```
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
import numpy
data = numpy.random.random(1000)
```

Now you've got a vector in python with 1000 elements, and if you want to do anything with it in R, you'll have to convert it. Your method A would result in something like this:

```
vecstr = "c({})".format(",".join(map(str, data)))
cmd = 'hist({},xlab="val", ylab="count", main="")'.format(vecstr)
ro.r(cmd)
```

Where `len(cmd)>15000`. You'd be better off writing everything to a file and just calling an R script separately (using python's `subprocessing` module, as mentioned above). Alternatively, you could do this, as in method B:

```
ro.r.hist(ro.FloatVector(data), xlab="val", ylab="count", main="")
```

Which is much cleaner, and won't have a problem if your vector has length 1million rather than 1000.

As to your question of efficiency:

```
In [29]: data1 = numpy.random.random(1000)

In [30]: data2 = numpy.random.random(1000)

In [31]: %%timeit
   ....: ro.r.cor(ro.FloatVector(data1), ro.FloatVector(data2))[0]
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

In [32]: %%timeit
   ....: vec1str = "c({})".format(",".join(map(str, data1)))
   ....: vec2str = "c({})".format(",".join(map(str, data2)))
   ....: ro.r("cor({},{})".format(vec1str, vec2str))
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.86 ms per loop
```

For a simple toy example that's not doing a whole lot, and a relatively small dataset, it appears to be about 5-6x faster to not convert to strings.